# Display image 5 second after hidden

Tags: swift, uiimage, uiviewanimation

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    // Set the image view in the starting location
    moveobj.frame = CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: /* some width */,                   
    height: /* some height */)

    UIView.animate(withDuration: /* some duration */, animations: {
        // Move image view to new location
        self.moveobj.frame = CGRect(x: 300, y: 300, width: self.moveobj.frame.width, height: self.moveobj.frame.height)
    }) { (finished) in
        // Animation completed; hide the image view
        self.moveobj.isHidden = true
    }
}
```

After animation is completed the image is hidden but I would like to display again this after 5 second in original position. How do I this?

Comment: Take a look at chaining a new animation in the finished block?

Comment: Or use `DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 5) { ... }`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well all you'd have to do is chain a new animation to the finish that does the opposite of the previous animation (move back to the original location and unhide) - Courtesy of @Rob's comment.

It'd just be:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    // Set the image view in the starting location

    let originalFrame = CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: /* some width */,                   
    height: /* some height */)
    moveobj.frame = originalFrame

    UIView.animate(withDuration: /* some duration */, animations: {
        // Move image view to new location
        self.moveobj.frame = CGRect(x: 300, y: 300, width: self.moveobj.frame.width, height: self.moveobj.frame.height)
    }) { (finished) in
        // Animation completed; hide the image view
        self.moveobj.isHidden = true
        // Next animation
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 5){
            self.moveobj.frame = originalFrame
            self.moveobj.isHidden = false
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In the 2nd animation block there's no need to animate the setting of the view's frame to `originalFrame` since the view is hidden. I'd reset the frame either just after the call to `...isHidden = true` or just before the call to `...isHidden = false`.

Comment: @rmaddy, so like what it is now?

Comment: Just one think this began to have erro  "Use of unresolved identifier 'DispatchQueue' "

Comment: and also have this erro  "Use of unresolved identifier 'originalFrame' "

Comment: @dinis, seems you must have a typo or are missing a curly brace. Putting this into a Playground has no errors.